# Inserting Data from a CSV into a Firebird Database using Python 3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, firebird, pyodbc

I am trying to take a CSV I created and insert it into a Firebird 2.5.8 database using Python 3. I have been using the pyodbc library and have been able to perform other other sql statements such as updates and selects so I know the connection is working correctly. However when it comes to a insert I struggle a bit. The CSV in particular contains blanks.

So far I have the following code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("""
select * from login""",conn)
# print(sql_query)



with open('Cleaned1.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header != None:
        # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
        for row in csv_reader:
            # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
            a = str(row[0])
            b = str(row[1])
            c = str(row[2])
            d = str(row[3])
            e = str(row[4])
            f = str(row[5])
            g = str(row[6])
            h = str(row[7])
            i = str(row[8])
            j = str(row[9])
            k = str(row[10])
            l = str(row[11])
            m = str(row[12])
            n = str(row[13])
            o = str(row[14])
            p = str(row[15])
            q = str(row[16])
            r = str(row[17])
            s = str(row[18])
            t = str(row[19])
           


            cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO VEHICALAVAILABILITY ('DATE', 'NODATE', 'DATEVBO', 'ETC', 'RELEASEDATE', 'VEH_REG_NO','VEHTYPE', 'AREA', 'DEPOT', 'NONCOMPACTOR', 'DESCDEFT', 'COMMENTS','VENDOR','NOTIFICATION','STATUSDATE', 'STATUS', 'DOWNTIME', 'VEHSTAT','VEHTYPE2','ATVENDOR') 
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s""", (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s,t))


conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details regarding your issue. Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say? If not, how do the results differ from what you expect? Also, since you apparently have pandas available, have you tried using `read_csv()` and `to_sql()` to copy the data?

Comment: Note also that pyodbc uses `?`, not `%s`, as the parameter placeholder.

Comment: According to https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor this is the answer @gordthompson

Comment: So switching from `%s` to `?` resolved your issue?

Comment: @GordThompson Different users (user13964273 is not the OP)